# Git pull doesnt work as expected

Tags: git, pull

... which probably is because I use it wrong.

Szenario:
I have a local repository and a remote repository (named staging). Now I developed on my local repository and committed and pushed it to my remote repository. Then, on my REMOTE repository, I added a file "newfiletest". I expected that when I locally do "git pull staging master", it should download the "newfiletest" file, which it doesnt.

Hope you get it :P I'm kinda new to git.

Comment: Did you commit the new file on your remote repository?

Comment: It would help if you show `git remote show origin` and `git branch -av`.

Answer (score 0):

So you did some work on your local repository and then you did

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Embrace my epic programming skills"
```

Then you decided you want to push it upstream to the remote so you did

```
git remote add <remote_name> <url>
```

and then

```
git push -u <remote_name> <branch>
```

Git will then asks you for your *username* and *password* for authentication reasons and poof! You pushed your stuff upstream.

Now then, you decide to make a new file (ex. .gitignore, readme.md etc.) on **Git Hub**. You do so and then run

```
git pull
```

This should fetch and merge your changes on top of your local repoistory

Comment: Not exactly. I didnt use Git Hub. I made a bare repository on a remote server with "git init --bare". And that repository I added locally as "staging".

So on that remote server i created a new file "newtestfile". Which isnt being downloaded to my local repository when I locally do "git pull staging master".

Comment: So, you configured your own server where you will be hosting your own git repositories? :s The above is an example with *Git Hub* i'd give it a try to get a feel for it before going more advanced and setting up your own server

Comment: Well... its actually just a web server where git is installed and a folder which I executed "git init --bare" in. And I dont really see the difference to your example. I'm doing the exact same actually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that unless you made a commit to your server, git will not be able to track that new file. Putting a file into the folder isn't enough, you need to make a commit too. I'm not sure if you can commit directly on a server, as I've never tried it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. use `git add` and `git commit` on the server to make the new file a part of your repository.

Comment: I understand. Well. It wouldnt solve my actual problem. I use it as a staging server for my customers to show the progress. When I push my local work to the server, a hook (post-receive) will put the files in a specified working dir. What I wanted is to be safe when someone changes something on the server. I wanted to git pull then to get the current state of the server.